# Brazil IR swaps and help with new holiday

Tags: derivatives, interest-rate-swap

Brazil has a pending new holiday that is expected to be official in the next month, for date Nov 20.
Existing BRL interest rate swaps contracts have a clause that fixed accruals are not impacted by new holidays, but float accruals are impacted.
How do I adjust my BRL swap accrual calculations once the holiday is official?
I thought I could just adjust the initial (PV) notional and day count, but that would impact both legs.

Answer (score 0):

New non-business days, one-off or annual, appear on various calendars pretty often even in developed markets. Recent examples come to mind: the Queen's funeral in London, the new King's coronation in London, the day of mourning for President George W Bush in 2018 in the U.S., and probably the same for Jimmy Carter any day now.

Fixed income markets have ways of dealing with new  non-business days. If a previously scheduled payment or settlement falls on such a day, then it gets [rescheduled like any other, according to the term sheet / documentation](https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dates.html#weekday-correction). If the interest amount is daycounted, then it too as adjusted for a new number of actual days.

But Brazil is special in that the interest of some instruments [accrues only on business days](https://www.clarusft.com/implementing-bus252-daycount-convention/). My understanding is that they don't want the interest amounts to change when the calendar changes. For that, you'd need to have two calendars - the one frozen as of the instrument's inception, to calculate the number of days of interest accrual as planned at inception; and also the current calendar still, to schedule coupon payments and settlements on current business days, like in all markets.